# SQL Query wildcard search

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql

Im writing a C# web page thats tied to a listview. My client would like to be able to type in something or part of something that it would show results. For example he wants a textbox where he may put in a phone number, part of a phone number, a name, city or whatever and there would be a SP of sorts that finds then lists the info. How can I accomplish this in either a SQL Sp or within VS 2010?

Comment: Try searching stackoverflow from the same "SQL Query wildcard search"...there are quite a few similar questions answered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`SELECT cols
FROM tbl
WHERE field LIKE '%' + @input + '%'`

Comment: zero! +1 because it works. -1 because you've just encouraged someone that is clearly new to SQL Server programming to write code that leaves themselves very exposed to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Doh, busted. "input" would be a parameter to your stored proc, not a variable in your application. Editing to show that.

Comment: @Rob Levine: And how would you inject a SQL in this? This is not a dynamic query. What am I missing?

Comment: @Andriy M - it has been edited. Originally it was a dynamic query (or at least, could have been). joelt has edited it to put the @ symbol in to show that this is now a parameterized query. You can view the previous edits by clicking the link next to "edited" just below the question - but you may already know that!

Comment: @Rob there was never any hint that this should be dynamic sql, since the original answer was only syntactically missing @. It otherwise doesn't confirm to any language specification for string concatenation.

Comment: @Richard aka cyberkiwi - Sorry, but I don't agree. It may not have been intended as dynamic sql, but by writing it out in that form it really does look like it says "take the sql string and concatenate the user input". Especially when answering questions to people who are starting out in a technology (e.g. SQL), it is always worth being clear. It would be all to easy for the OP to read the answer and go and implement it dynamically, because it appears to suggest that. Joelt has taken the criticism on board, amended his answer to be clearer and is now getting upvoted - as it should be.

Answer (score 3):

As several others have suggested, use the LIKE operator.

However, do NOT just put the data the user typed in directly into your LIKE clause like others have suggested. This leads to a very simple and very dangerous vulnerability known as a SQL injection attack.

If you insert the user's input directly into

```
SELECT cols FROM tbl WHERE field LIKE '%' + input + '%'
```

then a user could put the following in the text box:

> ;DROP TABLE tbl; --

(as an example), which makes your SQL statement become:

```
SELECT cols FROM tbl WHERE field LIKE '%';  (the first part of your query)
DROP TABLE tbl;    (the injected sql that you don't want to let people run; drop the database table)
-- '%'   (the rest of your previous query is commented out)
```

Always make sure you used parametrised SQL statements, or at the minimum sanitize your inputs. You really don't want people to be able to run arbitrary SQL on your database server.

Jeff Atwood (of SO fame) has a short [posting](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html) on this.
And it is worth reading [this](http://xkcd.com/327/) too :)

Answer (score 1):

Most everyone has hit on part of the solution -- use the LIKE operator.

But I think another aspect of the problem can be addressed in SQL.

Create a computed varchar(MAX) column.  Turn on a full text index on this field.  Then all you need to do is do a sql like:

```
SELECT * from <TABLE_NAME> WHERE Keywords like '%<search term>%'
```

This way you don't have to do `phone like <search>` or `name like <search>` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `LIKE` operator.

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE PhoneNumber LIKE '%value%' OR Name LIKE '%value%' OR 
City LIKE '%value%'
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to use one textbox** which could contain many different kinds of data, you need to be specific in your code about which database tables and columns you will search, and in what order.

For example, you might write a query that does this:

- First, search in the Customer table
  in the FirstName and LastName columns
  for a name LIKE the one in the
  textbox. SELECT the CustomerID for
  all of the matches.
- Next, search in both the Customer
  table and the Supplier table, in the
  PhoneNumber column, for a phone
  number LIKE the one in the textbox.
  SELECT the CustomerID or SupplierID
  for all of the matches. If any results are found, combine them with the results of the first query.
- Continue searching for street
  addresses, and querying other tables.
- Add new records to the resultset as
  you go along.
- After you have queried all of the tables that you want to search in, you will have a resultset containing ID's. You need to do another series of SELECTs to get the information you want to display to the user. If you mix customers and suppliers (and employees, etc), this could become quite complicated.

As you can see from this, **it would be much easier to have separate textboxes for each search criteria**. One textbox for first name, another for last name, a third for company name. A separate textbox for phone number. And if you are mixing data for customers, suppliers, employees, etc, you should have the user indicate (perhaps on a dropdown list or with checkboxes) which types of people to search, so you know which tables to query.